# NoClassDefFound Error and Document Exception while trying to do a select operation in hibernate via a servlet

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create a simple login page via JSP+Servlet using Hibernate.

`doPost()` of my Servlet class:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        System.out.println("Inside doPost() of Login Servlet!");
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("sapid"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("pass"));
        System.out.println("Role = "+request.getParameter("role"));

        User user=new User();
        Role role=new Role();

        user.setSapid(request.getParameter("sapid"));
        user.setPass(request.getParameter("pass"));
        role.setRoledesc(request.getParameter("role"));


        LoginServiceInterface service=new LoginServiceImpl();
        boolean status=service.validate(user,role);
        if(status)
        {
            HttpSession session =request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("user",user);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }
        else
        {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/sfp/loginerror.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }
    }
```

My Dao class:

```
package com.cba.quiz.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.cba.quiz.domain.Role;
import com.cba.quiz.domain.User;
import com.cba.quiz.util.HibernateUtil;
public class LoginDaoImpl implements LoginDaoInterface {

    @Override
    public boolean validate(User user ,Role role) {

        int resstat = 0;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<User> employee = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findRoleforaUser");

            query.setString("sapid", user.getSapid());
            query.setString("pass", user.getPass());
            query.setString("roledesc",role.getRoledesc());
            employee = query.list();
            transaction.commit();
            if (employee.size() == 0)
                resstat=0;
            else {
                resstat=1;
                for (User l : employee) {
                    System.out.println(l.getName() + "\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            session.close();

        }

        if (resstat == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

}
```

***Problem:***
When I try to run my Dao class as a stand-alone program (by changing the `validate()` to a `main()` method and passing some hard coded values in the `query.SetString()` such as `query.setString("sapid", "51527123");` etc), it works JUST FINE. But when I try to call the Dao class' method passing some values from the Servlet class, it throws some exceptions and errors.

***Console O/P***

```
Inside doPost() of Login Servlet!
51527690
asd
Role = user
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jul 04, 2015 4:25:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.cba.quiz.controller.LoginServlet] in context with path [/CBAQuiz] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
org.dom4j.DocumentException: C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse\src\dtd\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified) Nested exception: C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse\src\dtd\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at com.cba.quiz.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at com.cba.quiz.dao.LoginDaoImpl.validate(LoginDaoImpl.java:21)
    at com.cba.quiz.service.LoginServiceImpl.validate(LoginServiceImpl.java:15)
    at com.cba.quiz.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Nested exception: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse\src\dtd\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at com.cba.quiz.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at com.cba.quiz.dao.LoginDaoImpl.validate(LoginDaoImpl.java:21)
    at com.cba.quiz.service.LoginServiceImpl.validate(LoginServiceImpl.java:15)
    at com.cba.quiz.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

***Project Structure:***

[image: Project Structure]

***Mapping XMLs:***

*1) Role.hbm.xml*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "src\dtd\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.cba.quiz.domain.Role" table="roles">
        <id name="roleid" type="int" column="ROLEID" />
        <property name="roledesc" type="string" column="ROLEDESC" />
        <set name="users" cascade="all">
            <key column="roleid"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.cba.quiz.domain.User"/>
       </set>
    </class>
    <query name="findRoleforaUser">
        <![CDATA[select u from Role as r left join r.users as u where u.sapid=:sapid and u.pass=:pass and r.roledesc=:roledesc]]>
    </query>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

*2) User.hbm.xml*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "src\dtd\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.cba.quiz.domain.User" table="users">
        <id name="sapid" type="string" column="SAPID" />
        <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" />
        <property name="pass" type="string" column="PASS" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

***hibernate.cfg.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "src\dtd\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">soumava</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Role.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Can you find `hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` under `C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse\src\dtd` directory?. There should be something wrong in the configuration files and most importantly your hibernate configurations. So please update your question with xml configuraton files and remove the servlet classes.

Comment: I don't know why is it pointing there when I pass the values through servlet (No,the dtd is in my project folder and not the location it's pointing to). If there would have been any error in configuration, the standalone main() wouldn't have run right? Anyway I'll be updating the question with the configuration xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error clearly says, Hibernate can't find the file `C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse\src\dtd\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`. It is required by your XML configuration (referenced as `src\dtd\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`, note the relative path, which is resolved against the working directory).

When you run your program as a stand-alone app, the working directory is your project's root directory, so that relative path points to an existing file, as you expect. But when you run it as a web app, the working directory is something else, so that path points to a non-existing file.

To solve that, you should change the `DOCTYPE` in the configuration file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

and in the mapping files:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: I was doing it in my local drive,so I had to give the full path (including the drive), so I kinda figured it out from your answer!
+1